# pandas set comparison between workbooks - Python 3

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

If i need to see if values are the same between 2 workbooks within 2 column and if they are delete the row from the first workbook. Is there a faster way than to run it in a for loop? Ive heard of vectorised comparisons but don't know wether it'll be suitable in this case:

df1:

```
Match   ID1   ID2    ID1_source    ID2_source
x.1      1     2       a              b
x.2      2     3       b              c
x.3      4     5       c              a
x.4      1     3       b              c
x.5      5     6       a              b
```

df2:

```
Match    ID1     ID2     ID1_source    ID2_source   Notes  ...
 x.768    8       0         a            c           ///
 x.647    9       4         b            a           ///
  x.1     1       2         a            b           ///
  ...
  x.3     4       5         c            a           ///
```

In this example the row containing x.1 and x.3 would have to be deleted. Worth to note that each Match is unique with a unique ID1 and ID2.

Code:

```
ID1 = df1['ID1']
ID2 = df1['ID2']
gID1 = df2['ID1']
gID2 = df2['ID2']
For i in range(ID1)
    If  ID1[i] in gID1:
        gID1index= df2[df2==ID1(i)].index()
        If ID2[i] == gID2 [gID1index]:
            del df1.row[i] #dont know how to write this yet, but will find out
        else:
            continue
     else:
        continue
```

Comment: A very small example of your dataframes would help the answer :)

Comment: @Roelant sure thing, one sec

Answer (score 0):

You can use masks with dataframes. So

```
not_equal = (df1['ID1','ID2'] != df2['ID1','ID2']).all()
df1= df1[not_equal, :]
```